# Keycloak Springboot bearer only for specific endpoint and non bearer for another

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, keycloak, keycloak-spring-boot-starter

I am trying to use keycloak springboot adapter. I want to make some endpoints with "/api" work with bearer only to true.

But I also want the endpoint "/login" to not be a bearer only endpoint and redirect the user to the keycloak OIDC login page if he is not authenticated.

How can I achieve that ?

All I have now is just bearer only for every endpoints in my application properties.

Thanks in advance for your answers :)

Answer (score 0):

In web-security conf,

- enable anonymous
- in http-security ant-matchers, add an entry for your public routes with `permitAll()`

```java
    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.anonymous();
        http.authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/login").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated();
        return http.build();
    }
```

### PS

[Keycloak spring adapters are deprecated](https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/discussions/10187)

As an alternative, you can use:

- [spring-addons-webmvc-jwt-resource-server](https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons/tree/master/webmvc/spring-addons-webmvc-jwt-resource-server) tutorial [here](https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons/tree/master/samples/tutorials/resource-server_with_oauthentication)
- `spring-boot-starter-oauth2-resource-server` tutorial [there](https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons/tree/master/samples/tutorials/resource-server_with_jwtauthenticationtoken) (it requires more Java conf)